# Use different handling ways in except clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

Is there any better way to do the following:

```py
try:
    print(10 / 0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Can't do 10 / 0")

try:
    print(20 / 0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Can't do 20 / 0")
```

I want to do two different things that may result in the same exception and handle them differently.

There is probably no way to do this. I just want to make sure.

**Note:** I know that in the above example, I can use variables, but I will be using this pattern for more complex things and don't want this solution.

Comment: There is a way by setting 'checkpoint'. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/422678

Comment: The first should be asking a question why the things result in the same exception. Do you controll it? If so, maybe you could create your own exception.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge I do not believe this is possible. If it was different Errors that wouldn't be hard

```py
try:
    y = square(input('Please enter a number\n'))
        print(y)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        print(type(e), '::', e)
```

to

```py
try:
    y = square(input('Please enter a number\n'))
    print(y)
except ValueError as ve:
    print(type(ve), '::', ve)
except TypeError as te:
    print(type(te), '::', te)
```

But because you want it to be the same error type without the use of checking variables I do not believe there is a way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as Ricardo commented on the question, you can do it by setting 'checkpoint' [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/422677/handling-same-exception-thrown-by-different-methods/422678#422678). Also, this is how to do one thing that may result in two errors. My question is on how to do two things that may result in the same error and handle them differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try nesting exceptions. You can try handling the first error and if that passes, except the 2nd.   Without seeing exactly what you're doing, it's hard to say.  Below is an example of handling multiple exceptions.  Here's a tutorial for exceptions that also might help clear up the subject.
https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/#raising-an-exception

```
try:
    linux_interaction()
except AssertionError as error:
    print(error)
else:
    try:
        with open('file.log') as file:
            read_data = file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError as fnf_error:
        print(fnf_error)
```

Comment: Nesting exceptions with your method will have the second exception come up only if the first exception doesn't come up, so a `finally` block would be preferable. Also, this still uses two different `try`-`except` clauses. My question is if it is possible to do this with one `try`-`except` clause.

Comment: Again, without looking at your code and seeing exactly what you're trying to do, it's very difficult to give more then general advice on the subject.  The link I supplied should give you a good overview of how to handle errors in general.

Comment: I understand errors in general. My question is if it is possible to do the thing I showed in the example with one `try`-`except` clause.